# Why install anaconda in visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have installed `visual studio` and `anaconda`. But when I open visual studio and write python code, I am not able to run the program. Please help me.

Comment: What does "I can not run program" mean? Do you get no output? Do you get an error message? Does VS crash? What happens? Also, please include your code in the post

Comment: If you run `Visual Studio` why install `Visual Studio Code`?

Comment: Good question why you want to install anaconda **IN** Visual Studio